# Django non-blocking save?

Tags: django, asynchronous, save, nonblocking

Is there's way to call save() on an model in django, without waiting for a response from the db?
You could consider this async, though I need less, as async calls usually gives you callback- which I dont need here.
So basically I want -

`SomeModel.objects.bulk_create([list of objects ])`  , every say 1000 objects,
Without this line blocking my code. I will have no use in these rows in my code.
I'm looking for something simple, package like celery seems to offer way more than this..

Comment: Comparing celery to django is an apples and oranges comparision. Django is designed to make sure that all data is saved properly or to throw an exception when it cannot be. You are essentally turning django on it's head. However you can still pass this job to celery and be done with it.

Comment: The thing is I need to log some details for each visit in this view, and I dont want it to be slow because of this insert. Celery just seem to be too complex with too much dependencies for such a simple task

Answer (score 2):

As of 2016, Django is a web framework working (for the moment, if we are ignoring [channels](http://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) taking a HTTP request "as argument" and returns a HTTP response as soon as possible.

This architecture means there is no concept of asynchronous operation in the framework. If you want to delay saving and returns response to the user without waiting, you can:

- either run another thread/async block (which can be tedious with database transactions...) ;
- services like [IronWorker](https://www.iron.io/platform/ironworker/) that allows you to queue operations to run async a.s.a.p ;
- [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), that may bring too much features for your case but will do a better than job than some homemade solution.

Comment: Too bad. I do remember reading somewhere that other dbs like mongoDB does have "insert and proceed" option. So I might use it just for this.

Answer (score 0):

[rq](http://python-rq.org/) (Redis Queue) is another option for asynchronous operations (apart from those that Maxime Lorant mentions in his answer). It uses **Redis** as a broker (the middle man that holds the tasks) so if you are already using Redis or if you would like to add it to your project, you should consider it. It's a nice and simple solution, much simpler than celery. There is also [django-rq](https://github.com/ui/django-rq) a simple app that provides django integration for rq.

**Update**:
Summarizing comments

django_rq provides a management command (rqworker) that starts a worker process. Any job that is put in the queue will be executed by this process. You can either send one job to the queue for each object (a job would be a function with an object in its arguments and it will save the object in the database) or collect a list of objects and send a job with this list. In the second case you need to temporary store this list somewhere which might be tricky.

*Using redis to temporary store the objects (Recommended)*

I think that the most robust way to do it is to serialize objects to json and store them to a redis list. Then regularly check the length of it and when it has the desired length, you can send a job to the queue having this list in its arguments.

*Using worker's memory to temporary store the objects*

You could also use your worker's RAM as a temporary storage. This could be made since the worker process has its own memory. In this case the main process (the runserver) creates a job with an object. The job doesn't save the object, it just adds it to a list. You can keep appending objects to this list. Since the jobs are executed in the worker process, this list exists in the worker's memory. When it has the desirable length then you can save all objects.

But imagine the case in which you create more than one workers. In this case each job in the queue will be picked by the current free worker. So some objects will be appended in a list in the memory of worker_1, some other objects in the list of worker_2 etc. and you would have to deal with as many lists as workers.

Comment: What about django custom management command?  Couldn't figure how to access one that is already running

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Running a django command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/  which will work in the background and will do the writes to the db

Comment: That's my point, that the command is already in a separate process, my point is how do I "communicate" with it, and send objects to the command/rq process from my views code. I want from my view to send an object to be created, and after the process (rq or command) gets 1000 of these, it will batch insert them.

Comment: Ok I understand. There is no need to create a custom command. django_rq provides a management command (rqworker) that starts a worker process. Any task that is put in the queue will be executed by this process. U can either send a job to the queue for each object or collect some of them & send a job with a list. In the second case you need to temporary store this list somewhere which might be tricky. I think that the most robust way to do it is to serialize objects to json and store them to a redis list. Then regularly check the length of it & send a job when the length is 1000.

Comment: I see. Isn't it possible to somehow store the objects in the worker process itself? I mean, it is a process with its own memory right?

Comment: It is but I think there is no point to it in this case. Inter-process communication is usually done through a queue (redis). So again each object must pass through redis: main process creates a job with an object. Job is executed in the worker and saves the object in woker's memory -which might also be redis. Then if the list in worker's memory has the proper length you execute the database write.

Comment: You can access the worker memory in your jobs code, since the jobs are executed by the worker.

Comment: I didn't understand what is the 'worker memory'? In your example there is `long_running_task()` which is suppose to be run by a worker, how do I access some persistent memory from there (persistent in this context means, not local function memory)?

Comment: The worker process is a fork of the main process so initially they have identical data in memory. The long_running_task though, is executed in the worker so it can modify its memory. It can create a global variable, a list for example, that will exist only in the worker.

Comment: At least this is how I think this works. It needs some testing. The memory is the ram of the machine that runs the worker (either the same machine with the main process or a separate one).